# Asp.net core mvc Folder TreeView

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, treeview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tosrq.jpg)

How can I create this structure with Asp.Net Core? Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using TreeView. [take a look at this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/treeview-control-in-Asp-Net/)